# Hibernate left join does not return null rows when filtered using where condition

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have the below query in MySQL

```
SELECT Max(b.updated_at) as latest_date, r.resource, 
COUNT(bill) as bills FROM Resource r
left join BillComp ba on (r.resource=ba.resource and comp=6)
```

This returns null values if t could not map a resource with the given company which is the requirement.

I need to convert to HQL and I am having issues in returning null raws as expected.

I have tried below two methods but none works

```
    SELECT COUNT(bill), r.resource, MAX(b.updatedAt) FROM Resource r 
left join r.billComp ba left join ba.bills b where ba.comp.comp = ?1 

    SELECT COUNT(bill), r.resource, MAX(b.updatedAt) FROM Resource r 
left join r.billComp with ba.comp.comp = ?1 ba left join ba.bills b
```

Can someone show me how to get null values

I am using JPA Annotations

Comment: How try with this query `SELECT COUNT(bill), r.resource, MAX(b.updatedAt) FROM Resource r 
left join r.billComp ba where ba.comp.comp = ?1 `?

Comment: It's the same with or without the join to the bills table. In MySQL if you put the ba.comp = ? in where clause it does not return the null raws but if you put it in the join condition as I have shown at the beginning of the question, it returns null raws. I want to get this effect in HQL too